# Why dynamic colors don't apply in XML?

Tags: android, xml, material-ui

I try to add dynamic colors support in my XML+Compose app. In Compose I already added dynamic colors support, but for XML screen it's not work. What I do wrong?

My fragment .xml:

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorSecondaryContainer"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".base.MainActivity">
...
```

My Application file .kt:

```kotlin
class MyApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DynamicColors.applyToActivitiesIfAvailable(this) <- applied
    }
}
```

My Manifest file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:name=".base.MyApplication" <- added
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

My Theme file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_theme_light_primary</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/md_theme_light_onPrimary</item>
...
```

My Colors file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    <color name="md_theme_light_primary">#6750A4</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_primaryContainer">#EADDFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onPrimaryContainer">#21005D</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_secondary">#625B71</color>
    ...
```

I read [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/dynamic-colors) about dynamic colors on Android site, but it's not help.

Comment: The documentation you linked is [using a different parent theme](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/dynamic-colors#get-started-views). Is there a reason you are using the `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar` theme if you want dynamic colors?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, I applied this theme `<style name="AppCompat" parent="Theme.Material3.DynamicColors.Light">`. And it's works I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I changed my Theme file like this:

```
<style name="AppCompat" parent="Theme.Material3.DynamicColors.Light">

    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```